# Boost 1.67 - beast::websocket Error: resolve: Host not found (authoritative)

Tags: c++, boost, websocket, raspberry-pi, boost-beast

I am trying to use beast::websocket for my Raspberry pi project where Rpi is an IoT websocket client and Microsoft Azure WebPubSub is server-side.

I am new to C++ and Unix system. Sadly, I was unable to find that many useful reference projects using the C++ Websocket.

The first thing I wanted to do was to use the beast::websocket client example to successfully connect to a test websocket server.

Below is the example I used. [beast::websocket example 1.67](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/sync/websocket_client_sync.cpp)

```
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/connect.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;               // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
namespace websocket = boost::beast::websocket;  // from <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>

// Sends a WebSocket message and prints the response
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try
    {
        // Check command line arguments.
        if(argc != 4)
        {
            std::cerr <<
                "Usage: websocket-client-sync <host> <port> <text>\n" <<
                "Example:\n" <<
                "    websocket-client-sync echo.websocket.org 80 \"Hello, world!\"\n";
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        auto const host = argv[1];
        auto const port = argv[2];
        auto const text = argv[3];

        // The io_context is required for all I/O
        boost::asio::io_context ioc;

        // These objects perform our I/O
        tcp::resolver resolver{ioc};
        websocket::stream<tcp::socket> ws{ioc};

        // Look up the domain name
        auto const results = resolver.resolve(host, port);

        // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
        boost::asio::connect(ws.next_layer(), results.begin(), results.end());

        // Perform the websocket handshake
        ws.handshake(host, "/");

        // Send the message
        ws.write(boost::asio::buffer(std::string(text)));

        // This buffer will hold the incoming message
        boost::beast::multi_buffer buffer;

        // Read a message into our buffer
        ws.read(buffer);

        // Close the WebSocket connection
        ws.close(websocket::close_code::normal);

        // If we get here then the connection is closed gracefully

        // The buffers() function helps print a ConstBufferSequence
        std::cout << boost::beast::buffers(buffer.data()) << std::endl;
    }
    catch(std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Because echo.websocket.org is closed now. I used different test servers.
These are the command line for two different websocket test servers.

1. **sudo websocket-client-sync streamer.finance.yahoo.com 80 "Hello, world!"**

   Returned with **Error: The WebSocket stream was gracefully closed at both endpoints**
2. **sudo websocket-client-sync demo.piesocket.com/v3/channel_1?api_key=oCdCMcMPQpbvNjUIzqtvF1d2X2okWpDQj4AwARJuAgtjhzKxVEjQU6IdCjwm&notify_self 80 "Hello, world!"**

   Returned with **Error: resolve: Host not found (authoritative)**

I was able to connect both URLs with a websocket test client.
But unable to connect or keep connected through this beast example.

Especially, for the second server with an API key and forward slashes, I wasn't even able to find a host.

I thought this could be something to do with those special characters not recognized as literal?

So so far these are what I have tried.

1. I tried replacing / with /.
2. I specified the host in the cpp file
   (ex. **auto const host = "demo.piesocket.com/v3/channel_1?api_key=oCdCMcMPQpbvNjUIzqtvF1d2X2okWpDQj4AwARJuAgtjhzKxVEjQU6IdCjwm&notify_self";**)
3. Used encoded URL
   (ex. demo.piesocket.com%2Fv3%2Fchannel_1%3Fapi_key%3DoCdCMcMPQpbvNjUIzqtvF1d2X2okWpDQj4AwARJuAgtjhzKxVEjQU6IdCjwm%26notify_self)
4. used port 443 instead of 80
5. tried secure beast::websocket example over SSL for wss servers.

Nothing worked...

In the end, I need to use an Azure websocket URL with an access token which looks like this

**wss://lupo.webpubsub.azure.com/client/hubs/Hub?access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJ3c3M6Ly9sdXBvLndlYnB1YnN1Yi5henVyZS5jb20vY2xpZW50L2h1YnMvSHViIiwiaWF0IjoxNjMzNTc3ODA1LCJleHAiOjE2MzM1ODE0MDV9.1xGRvCsyc1QDTBWJ01PcTarx0judpa6ZuQ8**

Because this is the secure websocket, I used [this example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/sync-ssl/websocket_client_sync_ssl.cpp)
Successfully compiled with **sudo g++ -v websocket_client_sync_ssl.o -o wsstest -lpthread -lboost_system -lcrypto -lssl**

But no hope. Same result.. **Error: resolve: Host not found (authoritative)**

I feel like I am missing something pretty simple here. Could you help me out?!

Thanks!

Comment: The command line expects a host name not a url, you'll need to modify the example if you want to pass a url. `ws.handshake(host, "/");` is where you need to add the url path instead of `"/"`